Docker Nginx 404 Error on React Webpage (direct access or reload)
I'm working on deploying a React application using Docker with Nginx as the reverse proxy and static file server. The application runs correctly for the root URL (e.g., http://localhost:3000), but when I try to access any client-side route directly (e.g., http://localhost:3000/userForm), I get a 404 Not Found error from Nginx:
Error Message (no error message from nginx):

frontend-1  | 2024/11/01 23:13:44 [error] 30#30: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/userForm" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.21.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /userForm HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:3000"
frontend-1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2024:23:13:44 +0000] "GET /userForm HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"

It seems like Nginx is trying to locate an actual file or directory named userForm in /usr/share/nginx/html, but this route is handled by React Router on the client side.
Nginx Configuration:
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;  # Redirect unmatched routes to index.html
        index index.html;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/staticfiles/;
        autoindex on;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000";
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
}

Docker Setup: In docker-compose.yml, I'm mapping the React build output to /usr/share/nginx/html in the Nginx container: so C:\Users\bread\Documents\guess-the-rating\frontend\build⁠ Destination (Container) is /usr/share/nginx/html
nginx:
  image: nginx:alpine
  volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    - ./frontend/build:/usr/share/nginx/html
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  depends_on:
    - backend

React Router: In App.js, I have client-side routes defined like this:
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/userForm" element={<UserForm />} />
        <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
        {/* Other routes */}
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

What I’ve Tried:
Reading through stackoverflow.
Ensuring try_files $uri /index.html;: This line is in my nginx.conf file, which should theoretically serve index.html for any unknown routes. However, I still receive the 404 error.
Checking File Mappings and Nginx Configuration: I've verified that index.html and other static files are correctly located in /usr/share/nginx/html and default.conf are inside the Nginx container.
Testing in Development Mode: When running the React app with npm start (without Nginx), client-side routing works as expected, so this seems to be an issue specific to Nginx configuration or Docker setup.

The nginx configuration you provided is set to listen on TCP port 80, but you didn't map port 80 to 3000 in your docker-compose.yml file. The request you showed is targeting TCP port 3000. Additionally, your server block don't have the server_name localhost; directive, whereas the nginx error log entry indicates that the responding server block includes this line. Taking all of this into account, it seems likely that a different nginx configuration (or even a separate nginx instance) is handling your request.
